# Where is Wordpress search parameter checked?

Tags: wordpress, search

This is going to sound stupid but I am stymied. As I've learned a search form is recognised by Wordpress when the name of the input is gives as 's'. The action is always the home url. But nowhere in index.php or page.php(depending on your homepage setting) does it check for the parameter 's'. Where exactly does Wordpress check for this parameter?

I am trying to output the search result on a particular page but it does not work when I set the 'action' value to anything but the Home URL. I am hoping I can gain further understanding on how search works and maybe implement the same parameter checking in my desired page
[Howdy_McGee check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEyPO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress doesn't require that search goes back to the homepage. The `s` query var is a reserved keyword for WordPress search. What you can do is modify your search form to include the current url:

```
global $wp;

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( $wp->request ) ); ?>">
```

By doing so on a term page ( taxonomy archive ) it will also restrict the search to that specific term without any additional work. You can modify this in your `searchform.php` template. If you don't have one you can grab it from [the 2017 theme files](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/searchform.php).

---

WordPress parse most requests through the [`class-wp-query.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) file handed by the WP_Query Class/Object. Search is handled by [`WP_Query::parse_search()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_search/)

If you're looking to modify the search or really any queries you can always use [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) to change the query object before it's requested from the database. If you want to modify the SQL before it's requested you can use the [`posts_clauses`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/) hook, usually this is used for incorporating custom tables.

Comment: So I have different categories like 'famous people', 'articles' etc... and on each page template for each category I want to include a search function. The only thing that irks me is that searching for a post under certain category displays the result on the homepage, leaving the current page the user is on. So yes, bringing the page to the search result is viable but not preferable for what I am trying to accomplish. Meaning, the search result format I want for 'famous people' is different from let's say the search result for 'articles'.

Comment: @LianDiktea I gotcha. I've edited my answer. Search going to the homepage is not a requirement.

Comment: I have been toying with your solution. It works great for category pages and I am going to use your solution there. There is still one problem though, the list of personalities uses a different template altogether and so I use a static page which uses a custom template. Giving the page permalink as the 'action' value simply returns a failed search. Is it at all possible to return the search result on a page(not category page)? I'll include screenshots for better uderstanding

Comment: @lian are the list of famous people a post type? Could you change the search action attribute depending on whether you're viewing a page or taxonomy by saving the value as a variable and checking against `is_tax()`? Maybe using `template_include` would also help.